# PHP remove nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$templates` that looks like this:

```
        Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [displayName] => First Template
            [fileName] => path_to_first_template
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [displayName] => Second Template
            [fileName] => path_to_second_template
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [displayName] => Third template
            [fileName] => path_to_third_template
        )

)
```

And I want to make it to look like this:

```
        Array
(
    [path_to_first_template] => First Template
    [path_to_second_template] => Second Template
    [path_to_third_template] => Third Template
)
```

That is, I want the `fileName` of the nested arrays to be the new array's key and `displayName` to be its value.

Is there a pretty way to do this without having to loop through the array. I had no luck searching, as I didn't know exactly what to search for.

Comment: Looping through the array is obviously required, even if it happens behind the scenes. Why not simply do that?

Comment: @Jon Yes, I know. It was an attempt to keep my code simple and avoid having to include my own little library if there was a simpler way to do it with built-in functions. :-)

Comment: There is a way to do it, but it's really debatable if it's any better than `foreach`. I show both in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a classic `foreach` in action:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $row) {
    $result[$row['fileName']] = $row['displayName'];
};
```

Here's a "clever" way to do it:

```
$result = array();
array_walk($array, function($row) use (&$result) {
    $result[$row['fileName']] = $row['displayName'];
});
```

As you can see, the second approach is not really better than the first one. The only advantage is that theoretically you can pile upon the second form because it is a single expression, but in practice it's a long enough expression already so you wouldn't want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Loop in your array and make a new one:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $val){
    $newArray[$val['fileName']] = $val['displayName'];
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ret = array()
foreach ($templates as $template) {
    $ret[$template["fileName"]] = $template["displayName"];
}
```